# Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful while sending email using Action Mailer and office 365 email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, office365, actionmailer, digital-ocean

I have this code on my production.rb and development.rb.

```
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'mydomain.com' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:       'smtp.office365.com',
  port:            '587',
  authentication: 'login',
  domain:        'mydomain.com',
  user_name:   "username@mydomain.com",
  password:      "password",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  openssl_verify_mode: 'none'
 }
```

I am trying to send mail from my office 365 mail account using action mailer. This sends the mail perfectly fine on localhost. But it raises the following error during production. I am using digitalocean server.

> App 7718 stdout: [7bd99d32-f3c4-49c3-abfd-ff19fa7ddb8a] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8800ms (ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
>   App 7718 stdout: [7bd99d32-f3c4-49c3-abfd-ff19fa7ddb8a]
>   App 7718 stdout: [7bd99d32-f3c4-49c3-abfd-ff19fa7ddb8a] Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [CO2PR04CA0117.namprd04.prod.outlook.com]

I have searched everywhere on Google but most of them have solution for gmail not office. So, I couldn't find the exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  address: ENV['SMTP_ADDRESS'],
  port: ENV['SMTP_PORT'],
  domain: ENV['SMTP_DOMAIN'],
  authentication: 'login',
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: ENV['SMTP_USERNAME'],
  password: ENV['SMTP_PASSWORD']
}
```

I already have a office 365 account working with the above settings.

> The other thing that got me was you need to send from the actual account you're using to log in with. For example, don't send email from noreply@brownwebdesign.com and use support@brownwebdesign.com as your SMTP_USERNAME.

More info here: https://www.brownwebdesign.com/blog/connecting-rails-to-microsoft-exchange-smtp-email-server

Comment: I am using the email that I was using from long time. Also, I have the same email on both user_name and in default from. But it is still not working. And somehow, it is showing same error in localhost too now.

Comment: Then I guess.The problem is not on the code you have but on the microsoft's relay authentication. 
Can you use telnet to connect to the smtp from office 365 ? . Try connecting with telnet first into the smtp service.

Comment: It worked. Well, I was using the email say something@domain.com whose all mails were transferred to original@domain.com. So, I used the original@domain.com's credentials and used something@domain.com in default from and it worked perfectly. Thank You @xecutioner :)